# How to restore icons on the top-right corner in the Unity Panel?

Tags: icons, indicator, panel, notification-area

I just restored the left panel of Ubuntu using the post: [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears), but the icons on the top-right corner in the Panel are still invisible.

[image: example of missing icons]

I have searched but I haven't found anything that works for me on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Try to update your system and restart your system.

Comment: How to update my system? I have restarted thousands of times.

Comment: Do you mean run "Software Updater"? I have done that. No use.

Comment: Try the command "restart unity-panel-service" in terminal

Comment: tried, but error: "restart: Unknown job: unity-panel-service"

Comment: Check http://askubuntu.com/questions/476100/unity-and-the-tray-are-not-displayed-after-login and http://askubuntu.com/questions/468656/unity-crash-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: @vembutech: I don't know. When I power on the machine, an ugly blue login window takes over the usual login window and I have to log in from that login window. I don't know how to remove that ugly blue login. The question is described in: http://askubuntu.com/questions/563135/how-to-remove-the-ugly-blue-log-in

Comment: All these problems arise from trying those strange commands told by a sucker. It took me great trouble to restore the left panel, so I don't want to try them any more. I believe the problem is from the ugly blue login (it behaves like a virus). We should try to remove that login. If it is removed, I think the icons in the top bar will reappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By an accident I am unaware of, I selected lxdm as the display manager so an ugly blue login page comes out every time I tried to log in, as described in this question: [How to remove the ugly blue log in?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563135/how-to-remove-the-ugly-blue-log-in?noredirect=1#comment774909_563135). Now I run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and select lightdm as the display manager, all things I am familiar with come back again, including the lovely icons in the topbar.

PS: by executing `sudo apt-get remove lxdm`, we can completely remove that ugly blue login window forever.

Thank Seth for his help.