# Can not log into Ubuntu after update software and remove nvidia driver

Tags: unity, nvidia, login

The story began when I updated the software (I swear I will not update it again in future). The updater installed nVidia driver (I don't know why the updater installed nvidia because the ubuntu I use can not see the nvidia graphics card installed; it's a VM on Windows that does not support 3D graphics). Then, after I reboot and log in, only a wallpaper writing "Ubuntu 14.04 LTS" lies on the desktop. Answers to [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) does not work to restore the unity left panel and topbar, so I checked and checked to convince myself that that's because of the nvidia driver. So I uninstalled nvidia driver completely using the answer to [How can I uninstall a nvidia driver completely ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely). Then I reboot. Then after I input my password in the login, the same login window comes out again, again and again. I have also tried all commands in [unity and the tray are not displayed after login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476100/unity-and-the-tray-are-not-displayed-after-login), but the same problem persists. Here is a hint: when I run ccsm, I got "can not open display" error as the picture below shows. I'm not sure it is exactly the cause of the problem and I can not solve this problem either. So I need your help to pull me out of this trouble. If you need any information, please comment. Thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems a lot of people are having boot issues with the latest update. It appears it has to do with the newest kernel. It happened to me as we'll and I had to reinstall everything before I did a little research. What worked for me was the following:

Restar your machine and press shift to get to the Grub menu and select a previous version from your kernel. Let me know if it boots. Tomorrow I once I'm at my office I can help you remove the new kernel.

Comment: @Thank you. I selected "ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-43-generic (recovery mode)" in Advanced options, then I saw a menu in http://tinypic.com/r/2s9ugsm/8, which item should I choose? or should I select other options in Advanced options?

Comment: Hi, are you at office?

Comment: Sorry, I had a RL emergency and couldn't make it. I will help u tomorrow step bu step. Also, you do NOT WANT that 43ish kernel. That is the faulty one. Do you see other kernel versions listed?

Comment: Yes. Should I try the bare version or the version followed by (recovery mode)?

Comment: Yes and if you can list me the kernel versions that appear please

Comment: They are: 3.13.0-43-generic, 3.13.0-37-generic, 3.13.0-32-generic, 3.13.0-30-generic, 3.13.0-20-generic, 3.8.0-31-generic, with or without "(recovery mode)".

Comment: Try to load the -37 generic in normal mode and tell me if it works

Comment: I tried 37-generic, but not work; I still can't login.

Comment: I'm doing research. Can u boot with any kernel version sr all?

Comment: I tried all kernels. For all of them, I can boot, but I can not login

Comment: U get a black screen? Or how far can you get?

Comment: I'm on the login screen (LightDM, the display manager of ubuntu), input the password but the login screen appears again and again without taking me to unity.

Comment: Ok I see. You are on a loop. Mmmmmm so no kernel version allows you to login?

Comment: No. I don't think this is a kernel problem. This should be a simple configuration problem of LightDM used in ubuntu 14.04.